# What does the Webpack dev-server output mean?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Reading the Webpack 2 docs, Googling, and searching StackOverflow have failed me.

What do all these lines output from webpack-dev-server actually mean? In particular the `[36]` and `{0} {1}...` numbers and what the difference is between `[built]`, `[rendered]`, and `[emitted]`?

[image: screenshot showing output from webpack-dev-server]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers in braces ({0}, {1}, etc..) are the chunks generated, which you see under the chunks column.

[emitted] - output files, that are static resources, which includes the generated chunks

[rendered] - entry file that gets finally rendered on the browser

[built] - dependencies that've got bundled through the entry file